# Existe forma melhor para preencher esse array no node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Abaixo esta minha função do node.js (sou novo nisso), gostaria de preencher o array com numeros aleatórios (pode ser com tudo zero tambem), existe alguma forma mais rapida de fazer isso ? Do que eu estou fazendo ?

```
QLearn.reset = function() {
       for (var a=0; a<100; a++) {
        for (var b=0; b<20; b++) {
            for (var c=0; c<100; c++){
                for (var d=0; d<QLearn.action; d++){
                    QL[a,b,c,d]=Math.random();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Está pouco claro o resultado que queres obter... queres criar um array novo ou modificar um array já existente? O array é de uma só dimensão ou tem arrays dentro de arrays?

Comment: São arrays dentro de arrays `var QL = [[],[],[],[]];`  quero que a funçao inicialize o array e encha ele com numeros aleatorios. O importante é que ele faça isso do modo mais rapido possivel.

Comment: E os numeros aleatórios são quaisquer ou entre um valor defenido? Quantos numeros por array?

Comment: variando de 0 a 1 seria bom, mesmo que fose somente com zeros já seria interssante, o importante é que seja rapido.

Comment: Ok, viste a minha resposta? era isso que procuravas?

Comment: Fiquei na duvida, ainda precisaria colocar `for (var a=0; a<100; a++) {
        for (var b=0; b<20; b++) {
            for (var c=0; c<100; c++){ ` ????

Comment: O meu código substitui todos esses `for`. O resultado é uma array, com arrays dentro, cada uma com quatro numeros aleatorios de 0 a 1.

Answer (score -2):

Se estás em ambiente Node.js podes usar JavaScript moderno e fazer algo assim:

```
function randomArray(){
    return [...Array(4)].map(Math.random);
}
const start = +new Date(); 
var QL =  [...Array(100)].map(randomArray);
const end = (+new Date()) - start;
console.log(QL, end); // 2ms
```

Esse código gera 100 subarrays de 4 numeros aleatorios cada.